# Excel VBA: Find parameter, copy found row to another Worksheet (pasting starting at specific cell)

Tags: vba, excel

Having 2 Worksheets (**UPDATED,CHANGES**) each one have parameters in each column in variable order

**UPDATED** Worksheet has the columns:

*Name    /    Value    /    Units*

**CHANGES** Worksheet has the columns:

*Status / Name    /    Value    /    Units*

1. So first I search in **CHANGES** a row with the *Status*: CHANGE
2. Then I need to get the *Name* of that row
3. To find it in **UPDATED** and copy the whole Row
4. And copy it in the position after the column *Status* where the name was found

Each Name is unique but as I mentioned before has a variable position, my code so far:

```
Sub CopyRealChange()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Long, r As Long, x As Long
    Dim chng As Range
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("UPDATED")
    Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CHANGES")

    lr = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    x = 2
    For r = 2 To lr
        If Range("A" & r).Value = "CHANGE" Then 'Evaluate the condition.
            'Sh2.Range("B" & x).Value = Sh1.Range("B" & r).Value 'Copy same Column location
            'FIND
            With Worksheets(2).Range("a1:a1000")
                Set chng = .Find(sh2.Range("B" & x).Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If chng Is Nothing Then
                    sh1.Range(c).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("B" & x)
                End If
            End With
            'FIND
            
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Next r
   
    
End Sub
```

---

Concerns with the code show an error at this line (in the FIND)

```
sh1.Range(c).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=sh2.Range("B" & x)
```

Comment: What is your error?  What part of the code isn't working?

Comment: You probably don't need VBA for this, but hey it's whatever is best for your case.  I am just a big fan of "if you don't need vba don't do use it".  (INDEX and MATCH work wonders)

Comment: @Chrismas007 I update the question see above

Comment: @chancea As VLOOKUP, INDEX-MATCH work great with sorted data but with my list is constantly changed, deleted, updated and as far as my few knowledge go, it only use one parameter as reference to return the value, in my case, I use one to locate then get the value next to the one found  and update the info based on a search in other sheet, but if you could provide an insight answer with my case, I would check it out :).

Comment: @zegad Okay going through this, I believe its possible But I am actually confused on the functionality you want, you currently have a list of names on both sheets?  If thats the case, I could write a formula that grabs the "CHANGE" rows but they would of course just go away as soon as that word "CHANGE" went away.  What would make sense in my mind is if you wanted a list on the UPDATED sheet that ONLY had the "CHANGED" names.

Comment: @chancea That was the problem with the sheets I'm working on, is the different columns(see at the beginning of the question) that make it hard from my point of view, to use the excel formula, as _CHANGE_ is in only in the Status column only in the second sheet

Comment: @zegad the different sheets arent the issue.  It's just the fact that the functionality would be kind of pointless, PJs answer actually copies values over from the other sheet.  Formulas would just reference them, so basically it would just always update the values.... Probably not worth the effort to discuss the entire design of your spreadsheet just to show you how to do this with formulas if the macro works for you lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

You didn't declare with which worksheet the range you are searching for is located.

```
If Range("A" & r).Value = "CHANGE" Then
```

You declared the worksheets in the beginning then change how you reference them in the code.

```
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CHANGES")

With Worksheets(2).Range("a1:a1000")
```

**Here is what I've got for you:**  using simple loops checking to see if values match and move data.

```
Sub CopyRealChange()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim tempName As String
Dim lastRow1 As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("UPDATED")
Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CHANGES")

    lastRow1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'Get last row for both sheets
    lastRow2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'because you are searching both

    For s2Row = 2 To lastRow2                              'Loop through "CHANGES"
        If sh2.Cells(s2Row, 1).Value = "CHANGE" Then
            tempName = sh2.Cells(s2Row, 2).Value           'extra step for understanding concept
                                                           'There is a match, so now
            For s1Row = 2 To lastRow1                      'Search through the other sheet
                If sh1.Cells(s1Row, 1).Value = tempName Then                  
                    sh2.Cells(s2Row, 3).Value = sh1.Cells(s1Row, 2).Value    'Copy Values
                    sh2.Cells(s2Row, 4).Value = sh1.Cells(s1Row, 3).Value    
                End If
            Next s1Row
        End If
    Next s2Row
End Sub
```

Comment: Pretty sure it close to the answer but undefined variables found at      lastRow1, lastRow2, s2Row, s1Row so I try to define them as: `Dim lastRow1 As Range, lastRow2 As Range
Dim s2Row As Long, s1Row As Long` but still return error at execution

Comment: Nvm I found out both of them need to be defined as _Long_ to in the code, so update the code to select it as the right answer :)

Comment: @Zegad, thanks for catching that.  I honestly can't believe I overlooked that.  updated

Comment: You don't have to declare the s2Row or s1Row as long as you aren't using Option Explicit.